# Microsoft Access - Excel import and table update

Tags: excel, ms-access

I am currently working on a database for a small Company. They already have a first Version with several tables already implemented. What I would like to do is to create a master table in which data are going to be imported from Excel.
Everytime this table is updated, all the other tables should get updated aswell. 
I am not sure how to implement this in Access, so this is whz I am asking for help. 
Thanks in advance!
Maurizio

Comment: 1. Pls use the appropriate product tags only! Mysql has nothing to do with ms access or excel. 2. I do not think that your question would fly really well on SO because it is not specific enough. You are asking us to suggest design solutions to a problem you outlined in 2 short sentences. Even if you get any answer, they will be equally short, such as create a vba script in access that imports the data from excel and updates all relevant tables. Not sure how much help this would be to you or to anyone else seeking a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for **specific** questions. Please read [ask] and [help/dont-ask] -- Yeah, what Shadow wrote. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your Inputs and sorry for my mistakes. I will modify as you suggest my question

Answer (score 0):

Following sub will import data from excel to access table. Table structure and excel data structure must be same (Column name, data type etc).

```
Private Sub cmdSpecificSheetOnly_Click()
Dim strExcelPath As String

    strExcelPath = "C:\Users\HARUN\Documents\tblEmpInfo.xlsx"
      'For Specific Range
      'Call DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel5, "tblEmpInfo", strExcelPath, True, "Sheet1!A1:E31")
    Call DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel5,  "tblEmpInfo", strExcelPath, True, "Sheet1!")

End Sub
```

Comment: If you do not specify any range then it will import all data of a sheet.